# Recommendations table sort dataframe result in descending order Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, pandas-groupby, data-science

The recommendation tables output scores are not truly descending, the recommendations don't match the scores of the recommendationTable.

Currently, the input does work and it does give a correct recommendationTable_df.

```
recommendationTable_df = recommendationTable_df.sort_values(ascending=False)
```

**Note:** the output is correct  recommendationTable_df.head(6)

```
13    1.00
20    1.00
6     0.75
1     0.75
25    0.75
8     0.75
```

**However, when it goes to display the matching results that display id to name in the scored order It does not.**

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(recommendationTable_df.head(6).keys())] #adjust the value of 6 here
```

**At this point, the order is no longer descending or  correct**

but it is instead ordering by maybe the id that i am using to match to the name

```
    name    herotype    weapons     spells
1   niem    Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
6   sax     Bard    light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
8   wuc     Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
13  Rolf Rylan  Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
20  Braak Presley   Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
25  Jantroph    Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Abjuration
```

the order of the score should match the output with the id in the descending order of the score.

**This is what I am trying to achieve**

```
userInput = [
            {'name':'Rolf Rylan', 'rating':1}   #Their is no rating system is being used thus by default rating is set to 1
         ]
```

**recommendationTable_df  with Exspected Results match up this is not a real dataframe**

```
13    1.00    |    13    Rolf Rylan  Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
20    1.00    |    20    Braak Presley   Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
6     0.75    |    6     sax     Bard    light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
1     0.75    |    1     niem    Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
25    0.75    |    25    Jantroph    Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Abjuration
8     0.75    |    8     wuc     Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
```

**I instead get this as the results which is not matching the decending order**

```
13    1.00    |    1   niem    Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
20    1.00    |    6   sax     Bard    light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
6     0.75    |    8   wuc     Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
1     0.75    |    13  Rolf Rylan  Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
25    0.75    |    20  Braak Presley   Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
8     0.75    |    25  Jantroph    Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Abjuration
```

How would I get it the recommendation data frame to match the order of the recommendation tables output scores.

**This is the recommendation tables output scores**
Which are in the correct order

```
recommendationTable_df.head(6)
```

**output**

```
13    1.00
20    1.00
6     0.75
1     0.75
25    0.75
8     0.75
dtype: float64
```

**This is how it Sorts the Score**

```
#Multiply the genres by the weights and then take the weighted average
recommendationTable_df = ((genreTable*userProfile).sum(axis=1))/(userProfile.sum())

#Sort our recommendations in descending order
recommendationTable_df = recommendationTable_df.sort_values(ascending=False)

df.loc[df.index.isin(recommendationTable_df.head(6).keys())] #adjust the value of 6 here
```

**This is the current recommendations** This order is not correct

```
    name    herotype    weapons     spells
1   niem    Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
6   sax     Bard    light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
8   wuc     Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
13  Rolf Rylan  Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
20  Braak Presley   Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
25  Jantroph    Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Abjuration
```

**This is the result I was trying or expecting to get**

```
        name    herotype    weapons     spells
    13  Rolf Rylan  Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
    20  Braak Presley   Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
    6   sax     Bard    light crossbow, battleaxe, Dagger, sling, club  Necromancy
    1   niem    Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
    25  Jantroph    Paladin     light crossbow, battleaxe   Abjuration
    8   wuc     Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy
```

**based on the output**

```
   13    1.00
   20    1.00
   6     0.75
   1     0.75
   25    0.75
   8     0.75
   dtype: float64
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are trying to do, perhaps you can show us your input?

Comment: I will edit to hopefully clarify. Trying to sort the descending 6 based on the recommendationTable_df scores - the first # is the id and the second is the score. so the id of 13  is the name Rolf Rylan is 1.00 perfect match for himself as he is Rolf Rylan the next result should be the id of 20 who is Braak Presley which has all matching  across the 3 sets of categories herotype,weapons and spells plus he has a additional thing so heis also 1.0.

Comment: `df.loc[recommendationTable_df.head(6).index, :]`

Comment: Awesome that should probably work

Comment: @PMende Thanks that works perfectly. How do I accept your answer? The results match the table in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by PMende in comments I changed

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(recommendationTable_df.head(3).keys())]
```

into

```
df.loc[recommendationTable_df.head(6).index, :]
```

Now it does match

```
#Multiply the genres by the weights and then take the weighted average
recommendationTable_df = ((genreTable*userProfile).sum(axis=1))/(userProfile.sum())

#Sort our recommendations in descending order
recommendationTable_df = recommendationTable_df.sort_values(ascending=False)

#df.loc[df.index.isin(recommendationTable_df.head(3).keys())] #adjust the value of 3 here

df.loc[recommendationTable_df.head(6).index, :]
```

so if I enter the character name Odorr Spalding, I get him back Odorr Spalding with a score of 1.0 and the descending matches in order.

[image: results matching]